# How to track "Last Activity" with ASP.NET MVC4 Action Filters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to maintain a "Last Active" DateTime field on every User's Profile - Originally I was going to tie this check to some Index() controller but the user might not always call that controller, so I need something global.

Action Filters seem to apply on the Controller level at the highest, so now I'm wondering if some magic in Global.asax might do the trick.  This seems like a common enough problem but I wasn't able to pull anything up in the Google or on SO - apologies if it's a dup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "the user might not always call the controller"? If you have an mvc web application, then user interaction will always be with an action on a controller.

However, I would suggest using an ***HTTP*** module. An ***HTTP*** module class will always run for each call, and I think it will be a better choice for your issue. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307996 might be a good reference for that, or just google it and you will find many results that help you with implementing it.

**Edit**:

If you have already implemented a filter, you can apply it to all actions simply by adding  code simlar to below to your ***global.asax*** (`applicaton_start()` method)

```
var myfilter = new MyFilter();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(myfilter);
```

Comment: Thank you - what would the contents of MyFilter look like?  "the user might not always call the controller" > the user will call a controller, but not every controller.  I'd like to avoid peppering filters onto every controller in my app if I can avoid it.

Comment: Yes the above code would register the filter for all controllers. Regarding the content of MyFilter, if you mean business wise I don't know your business but I would expect you making a call to the database to save the current time. If you mean regarding how to write a fitler in general, then this link might help you http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters